# Time Complexity between JFC's HashMap and TreeMap?

Tags: algorithm

From my understanding,

```
TreeMap :
1. Insert O( logN )
2. Delete O( logN )
3. Retrieve O( logN )
HashMap :
1. Insert O( 1 ) -> O( N )
2. Delete O( 1 ) -> O( N )
3. Retrieve O( 1 ) -> O( N )
```

I know that TreeMap using Red-Black tree as internal data structure. However, I'm not so sure about HashMap's internal data structure.

1. Is HaspMap implemented using
   Hash-Table?
2. If the answer is "Yes", then does it use array-base's implementation
   or reference-base's implementation?
3. And if it used array-base then is it sorted or unsorted?

I'm working on a small project using Java to demonstrate the runtime complexity of all operations( insert, delete, retrieve ) between HashMap and TreeMap, but I don't really know how to link the theory formula with actual result from running a program. For example, from running a quick test :
1. Insert 10,000 elements
2. Delete 100 elements
3. Retrieve 100 elements

I got this info:

```
     HashMap
Create time : 6348015 nano seconds.
Remove time : 98458 nano seconds.
Retrieve Found time : 59762 nano seconds.
Retrieve Not Found time : 39097 nano seconds.
 --- end ---

     TreeMap
Create time : 20518163 nano seconds.
Remove time : 274221 nano seconds.
Retrieve Found time : 112072 nano seconds.
Retrieve Not Found time : 168442 nano seconds.
 --- end ---
```

I would like to know how can I find the link these times with the theoretical time complexity such as O( N ) or O( logN )?
And this result surprised me since I always think TreeMap would beat HashMap badly. Could anyone give me some brief explanation about these things? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the complexity of some operation, you can't just use one data point, you have to show how the time changes when `N` changes.

Also, often algorithms or data-structures with better theoretical complexity have worse running times for smaller data-sets.

Another thing to think about is to have representative values. For example if you insert values `1, 2, 3, …` into an RB-tree, that's the worst-case scenario (I think), because it has to rebalance quite often. Inserting random values will probably give different result.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen videos on youtube that explain the different sorting algorithms both through animation and graphs. Note also that Big-Oh is **worst case** running time, so you may need to rig it so that the worst case is hit to highlight the differences.

I think a simple graph would be best, with time on the y-axis and number of elements on the x-axis.

Comment: The big-O notation doesn't necessarily mean worst-case.

Comment: @svick: Actually it does (well unless you're talking about a context where more is better, in which case it would be the best case). O describes the upper bound, Ω describes the lower bound and Θ describes both.

Comment: Yeah, it describes the upper bound, but that doesn't mean it always describes the worst case. For example, quick sort is in average case O(*n* log *n*), but the worst case is O(*n* ²).